# Toast notifications in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, toastr

I want to display notifications whenever a user click on the "Add to Cart" button using the Toastr plugin. Basically, when a user click on the button, it executes the action "AddToCart" then redirects to the index page. When the page shows up, it checks the TempData value, then shows the notification.

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {


        TempData["message"] = "Added";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and the view:

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {   
            toastr.success('Added')
        })
    </script>                                 
}
```

**Update**
it worked according to @Exception's answer. However, if I use ajax such as:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Home", new { id = item.ProductId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="abc"})
```

it doesnt work. That may be because of the line:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

as the page is not reloaded.
How can I fix it?

But this doesnt work.
Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see any console errors..

Comment: There is no console error

Comment: i will recomment you to take html.actionlink..then your problem will be solved..

Comment: Html.Actionlink is ok, but I want to use Ajax so that the page doesnt have to be reloaded like other websites.

Comment: as per your question in AddToCart action it is redirecting to index then also page will be reloaded..

Comment: But I didnt see the page reloaded when using Ajax.

Comment: one thing you can do is that inside div with id "abc" there put script tags and check updated value of viewbag..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Answer 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
       if('@TempData["message"]' == "Added"){
          toastr.success('Added');
       }
       else{ }
    });
</script>
```

### Answer 2:

Although `TempData` retain its value on one redirect but sometimes it creates problem(and it is recommended to avoid using `TempData`) in that case you can do as:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
{
    .........
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { message="Added" });  //Send Object Route//
}

public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    .........
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) {
       Viewbag.message=message;
    }
    return View();
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
       if('@Viewbag.message' == "Added") {
          toastr.success('Added');
       }
       else{ }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, there is. I set a break point and checked it. The data was "Added", but it somehow still didnt execute the code inside the if statement

Comment: instead of "=="  try "===" and check..@TungPham

Comment: its weird. I tried to add a line "@TempData["message"]" just under the "toastr.success('Added');" and set a breakpoint on it. it still was executed (but didnt show anything) even the TempData was null. @@

Comment: I got an error "Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'" on the line "if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty)"

Comment: ok ok. I accepted your answer. Anyway thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in Index Method the ViewBag statement, which contains a TempData variable:

```
....
ViewBag.message = TempData["message"];
....
return View();
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@if (ViewBag.message != null)
```

{

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {   
        toastr.success('Added')
    })
</script>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This link might help: https://github.com/fatihBulbul/toastr.Net

Server Side:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message =  Notification.Show("Hello World", position: Position.BottomCenter, type: ToastType.Error, timeOut: 7000);
        return View();
    }
```

Client Side :

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
TempData["message"] = "Added";
```

**View**

```
    @section scripts
{
        <script >
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if ('@TempData["message"]' == "Added") {
                    toastr.success('Action successfully changed....', 'ActionName');
                }
                else { }
            });
    </script>
}
```