# Showing a popup modal to random view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a background service which is listening for events. when ever an event occurs i want to display a popup (partialview modal). How can i realise to display a popup on a random View where the user is located at the moment the event occurs?

Comment: I think you're talking about "toast". This is a javascript library which would need to be embedded in your master page

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300557/toast-notifications-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 0):

add a Controller called `HomeController`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(UserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Content("true");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

and add `View` called Add

```
@model UserViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<form method="post" action="/Home/Add" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Family"></label>
        <input asp-for="Family" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Family"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

in `_Layout.cshtml` add this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - PopupModal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/toast/toastr.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>


    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="form-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/toast/toastr.min.js"></script>

    <script>
          showInPopup = (url, title) => {
             $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
                  url: url,
                     success: function (res) {
                        $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res);
                        $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
                        $('#form-modal').modal('show');
                     },
                     error:function (err){
                     }
                    })
                }

            jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
               try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: form.action,
                    data: new FormData(form),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (res) {
                        if (res=="true") {
                            toastr.success('success','message');
                            $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                            $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                            $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                })
                //to prevent default form submit event
                return false;
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex)
            }
        }
    </script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

in `Index.html` add this code

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    <a onclick="showInPopup('/Home/Add','Add')" class="btn btn-success text-white">Add</a>

</div>
```